# Firebase Cloud Function - Create user with extra information

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am currently looking for the best way to create a user with additional information in a cloud function. The obvious possibility seems to create a trigger which creates a user document:

```
functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => { /* Create user document in firestore with base information*/ });
```

And afterwards add the information to the created document. (Handle the promise)

But one way or another I don't feel really satisfied with this solution. I would rather do all this stuff in one go. Does someone have a better solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "additional information" ? What's the source of this information ? Is it first name, last name and something like that ?

Comment: Yes, first name, last name, gender, ...

Comment: What is the problem of the auth cloud function? In my team we actually moved from auth trigger, to just writing the data to the backend, after successful user creation to help solve some timing issues. Thats the only disadvantage of the auth trigge in my opinion, i.e. you don't know from a client perspective when it's done.

Comment: Handle the data in a single request can prevent data issues, reduces time, ... I would rather not fully rely on the client side code to fill in the additional info.

Comment: What do you mean "I would rather do all this stuff in one go"?

Comment: One go means in one operation from client to firebase

Comment: You can not do it in one operation, you have to create the user then when promise fulfilled get id then you save the additional data

Comment: And what if you create an HTTP Cloud function in which you post email, firstname, lastname, password, etc... Like in this ticket https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43806750/can-i-create-a-user-on-firebase-authentication-in-cloud-functions-http-trigger. I guess I'm going to it that way.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to save additional user data in firebase I would recommend to handle this in your front-end after the newly added user is registered.

In your front-end once the registration promise is fulfilled, get the userid and perform a database set for example in `users/${userid}` with the initial data you want to save.