# Firebase onCompleteListener code being skipped

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm making an app where a signed-in user can create another account, so in this code, another user is already signed in, check the toasts to see the order the code is being executed.

```
 btnCreateCompany.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtCompanyEmail.getText().toString(), txtCompanyPassword.getText().toString())
                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP SECOND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    if (!task.isSuccessful())
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOMETHING WENT WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    else {
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP THIRD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        FirebaseUser userCreated = task.getResult().getUser();
                                        userCreated.sendEmailVerification();
                                        userID = userCreated.getUid();//userID is a private field
                                    }
                                }
                            }); //After reaching the third toast the code adter onComplete doesn't execute anymore

                    if (userID == null)
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP FIRST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    else {
                        companyRef = db.collection("companyData").document(userID); (...) }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating the user is an asynchronous operation. Any code that needs access to the newly created user, needs to be inside the `onComplete` method or be called from there.

So something like:

```
btnCreateCompany.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        firebaseAuth
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(txtCompanyEmail.getText().toString(), txtCompanyPassword.getText().toString())
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP SECOND", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) }
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SOMETHING WENT WRONG", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP THIRD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        FirebaseUser userCreated = task.getResult().getUser();
                        userCreated.sendEmailVerification();
                        userID = userCreated.getUid();//userID is a private field
                    }
                    if (userID == null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "THIS TOAST IS COMING UP FIRST", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else {
                        companyRef = db.collection("companyData").document(userID); (...) }
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to:

```
 task.getResult().getUser();
```

may not work. Try to log firebaseauth.getCurrentUser() and task.getResult().getUser() inside task.isSuccessful() to better understand what's going on.

I can suggest different approaches to this if you fail to debug:

1) Set up the Firebase Admin SDK to create a new user from your app:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

OR

2) Set up a cloud function using Node.Js like this one:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43808854/13473423

and then call your cloud functions to create and new user from your app. Handling it on the server side means it won't interfere with the "Current" FirebaseUser and thus will work!

Check this answer on how to call cloud functions locally:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works. So try to replace this line

```
FirebaseUser userCreated = task.getResult().getUser();
```

with this:

```
FirebaseUser userCreated = firebaseauth.getCurrentUser();
```